# Adjust rotated axis labels to ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have rotated my ggplot - geom_bar axis labels 90 degrees, and now want the labels to be aligned with the ticks. is this possible as seen below they are slightly slanted to the right of the tick?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adjust text position with `vjust` option (theme in `p2` is what you need).

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- qplot(rownames(head(mtcars)), 1) +
    ggtitle("vjust = 0") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0))
p2 <- qplot(rownames(head(mtcars)), 1) +
    ggtitle("vjust =  0.3") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]